# Identify power cable connector

Tags: connector, identification

I need help identifying this connector. It looks a bit like a Mate-n-Lock but I was not able to find this layout in their list. I also browsed Digi-Key, Mouser and a couple of auto parts sites, to no avail.

This carries 230 VAC, about 30 mA.

[image: An unidentified 3-pole connector]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a 3-pin [Molex 3191](https://www.molex.com/molex/search/partSearch?query=3191).

It's available on both [Digi-Key](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/molex/0019091039/WM1604-ND/26358) and [Mouser](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Molex/19-09-1039?qs=404muyNbhLHVihSpLlW0cA%3D%3D).

[image]

Comment: That was quick. Thanks!